# Cannot define my variable in python program

Tags: python

I am required to make a function that provides a **Semester Summary** that includes courses taken, credits taken, GPA points, and Semester GPA. I have this first function working

**- gpacalc()**

However, when I try making the second function

**- coursePoints(credit,grade)**

Which is supposed to return the "GPA points" of one specific class when you enter the credit of the class and the grade received.
This is where I run into issues. **It says "gp" isn't defined.** I know this is a lot but I think it is probably a simple error. I am probably shadowing my variables, which I still can't quite figure out. If you can help, I appreciate it!

```
# coursePoints requirement
def coursePoints(credit, grade):
    gp = 0.00
    totalcredits = 0
    totalpoints = 0
    # I have lots of if statements here, I deleted them for simplicity.#
    gp = round(totalpoints,2)/round(totalcredits)

print("The GPA points of this class is:", round(gp))

coursePoints(3,"b")
```

Comment: Did you remember to declare "gp" as global variable?

Comment: how do you declare it as a global variable?

Comment: Why not return `gp` from `coursePoints` and print the result of the function call?

Comment: The `print()` line at the end needs to be indented so it's part of the function.

Comment: BTW, the fact that you have a large block of identical code in both functions that converts letter grades to points suggests that you should create a separate function for that operation.

Comment: This is too much code for a simple problem. Please provide a [mre], including the full error message. The issue is dead-simple: `gp` is not defined here: `print("The GPA points of this class is:", round(gp))`

Comment: Good point. I will edit it to make it more simplified.

Comment: @Barmar, that was the problem... I feel quite dumb now!! Thank you for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an indentation on `print("The GPA points of this class is:", round(gp))` for it to be inside your definition of function `coursePoints()`.

Without the indentation, it's as if you're trying to print a variable in your file that hasn't been given any value, nor declared.

Also, if you input "b" instead of "B" in `coursePoints()`, as per the last line, it will return a GPA of 0, since you've only specified capital letters. OR you add the option of analyzing bot letters in if with `if grade in ["B","b"]:`. OR an even simpler solution is to add `grade = grade.upper()` right below `def coursePoints(credit, grade):`, and mantain everything else the same (props to wjandrea).

The ending of the code should be:

```
[...]
    elif grade in ["D-","d-"]:
        totalpoints = totalpoints + (credit * .67)
        totalcredits = totalcredits + credit
    else:
        totalpoints = totalpoints + (credit * 0)
        totalcredits = totalcredits + credit
    gp = round(totalpoints,2)/round(totalcredits)
    # next line is indented now, thus, inside coursePoints()
    print("The GPA points of this class is:", round(gp))

coursePoints(3,"b") # change if condition for elif grade in ["B","b"]:
```

Edit: corrected and expanded as per wjandrea's comment.

Comment: Correction: `grade in ["B", "b"]`. But it's easier to do `grade.upper() == 'B'` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. Such an easy fix... and good catch on the capital letters! In my other function I have the .upper() to make them capital letters. In this function I will have to do the == ["b", "d-"].